# Conversion from one class vector type to another in c++

Tags: c++, class, type-conversion

I have an inherited class InhClass which is derived from a Base Class (abstract class). In my Inherited class i have to override a function of Base Class which returns a vector of some devicetype class objs. In that function i am using an external library function which is returning a vector of different class type.

```
Inherited Class
std::vector<devicetype> basefunction(){
externalclassfunction();    // returns std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BluetoothDevice>>                 
}
```

Is there any way to convert the vector of external library class unique pointer (BluetoothDevice) to the vector of class of devicetype class?

Comment: Can you shouw us th edefinition of `Inherited` and the base class? And some information about the external library too

Comment: In theory you can cast vetors, but `BluetoothDevice` and `devicetype` must be compatible for that operation

Comment: Not possible with a simple cast, you always need an underlined copy-semantic: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18223036/i-want-a-vector-of-derived-class-pointers-as-base-class-pointers

Comment: What is the relationship between `devicetype` and `BlueToothDevice`?    Are they both classes, and one is inherited from the other?   Is `devicetype` an enumerated type with particular possible values representing a bluetooth device?   Or something else?

Comment: @Ivan
Base Class Function:
virtual std::vector<devicetype> getConnectableDevices() = 0;

Inherited Class Function:
std::vector<devicetype> getConnectableDevices(){
externallibraryfunction();             //returns std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BluetoothDevice>>
}

Comment: Consider using template instead of inheritance.

Comment: @frachop Virtual functions are not possible to define with templates. Is there any other thing you can suggest?

Comment: @Arsalan Raghib : see [Standard practice virtual interface classes vs templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165963/c-standard-practice-virtual-interface-classes-vs-templates) or [templates vs inheritance](http://groups.di.unipi.it/~nids/docs/templates_vs_inheritance.html)